# Ionic post API error unauthorized

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ionic-framework, asp.net-web-api, ionic3, postman

I use Ionic to build App, I would like post on API that I prepare I test
API using postman it works correctly
but when I use Ionic face an error 405 Method not allowed
this is the response for request:

> {"Message":"The requested resource does not support HTTP method 'OPTIONS'."}

I got status 200 on postman but 405 using ionic

Postman:

[image: Postman]

This is my code:

```
var auth = 'bearer ' + Token;[enter image description here][1]
let headers = new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'withCredentials': 'true',
        'Authorization': auth
    });

    return this.http.post('http://abdalrahmannada-001-site1.htempurl.com/api/Rabbit/AddRabbit', { headers: headers })
        .map(response => response);
```

Comment: is cors enabled on your api?

Comment: no what should i do?

Comment: I add this code to web config

Comment: <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS" />
         <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
        </customHeaders>
      </httpProtocol>

Comment: its problem of back end . You need to enable cors .

Answer (score 0):

this problem relate to server side
you should want from admin server provider to enable http option for you

most hosting disable this for security